# Conditional statement without using if-else in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

So here is the question.
There are 2 variables having values of 3 and 5 respectively.
if the user enters 3, "5" should be printed and vice versa.
implement the code without using if-else.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
# take integer input from user
c = int(input("Enter a number: "))

print(c == 3 and 5 or c == 5 and 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

another thing you could try is using the tuple ternary using the `(when_false, when_true)[condition]` logic:

```
    x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    change_integer = (3, 5)[x == 3]
    print(change_integer)
```

Returns 5 when input is 3 (as the condition is 'True') & returns a 3 when input is 5 (as the condition is 'False'). Note that it will always return a 3 *unless* the input is 5, so this will only be useful if you only accept the two variables 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

In python it can be simply achievable using subtraction, because conditionally we know both of the input value.

```
def two_variables(value):
    return 8-value
```

print(two_variables(5))

```
3
```

print(two_variables(3))

```
5
```